# Expose Odoo on internet after installed locally

Tags: odoo

Im wondering if you can help me to expose Odoo 14 on internet through a subdomain in my shared host.

I've installed Odoo 14 on Ubuntu server on virtual machine and now i want to expose Odoo on internet.
I have installed nginx on ubuntu and configured it successfully. (Maybe im wrong here :/)

Till now I can access my apache server from guest to host successfully but localhost with another port, for example odoo port 8069 it is impossible. I tried different adapters from guest to host as nat, bridge, host only but i cant access odoo firstly on host then expose it on internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup nginx properly, you should probably access it on port 80/443 (depending on your config). If you dump your nginx settings here, I can assist you more.

Comment: Hello, I followed this tutorial so this is config about that https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-odoo-14-on-ubuntu-20-04/#configuring-nginx-as-ssl-termination-proxy

Comment: your nginx settings listens on 80 and 443 (80 is forwarded to 443) if you don't have these port engaged on the host, you should be able to open odoo on 443. But I guess (based on your answer) that you have also apache on your host which is probably listening on 443 and 80, so nothing will go to nginx.
I suggest removing nginx from your VM, then you can open it on 8069 but odoo chat won't work in multi-process mode. If it worked, then you can setup apache by doing similar configs as https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it and if it doesnt work i will continue to chat.